# Pymc: Does this model call for Index, and if so, how would I use it?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I'm working on speeding up the mcmc for a hierarchical pymc model that is taking .2 seconds per iteration.

It's the second model from [this paper](http://www.statistica.it/gianluca/Research/BaioBlangiardo.pdf), modeling a soccer league using team-specific attack and defense 'strength' parameters.  There are three 'tiers' of strength, with a team drawing it's attack and defense parameters from the distribution corresponding to its tier:

[image]

[image]

An excerpt of my pymc code is below.  While thinking about how to speed up the mcmc, I came across this in the pymc documentation on deterministics:

> Index is useful for implementing dynamic models, in which the
>   parent-child connections change.

I think that describes this model, in that the parents of the team-specific parameters vary depending on which tier they are in.

**Questions**

1. Is this model an instance in which using Index is applicable and/or would make the mcmc faster? If so, how would I use it?
2. If the answer to 1. is no, are there any other changes I could make to speed up the mcmc?
3. I get the sense that sticking to numpy arrays as must as possible is a best practice. Are there any other best practices for setting up a model in pymc?

Code excerpt:

```
num_teams = 20
NCT_DOF = 4

mu_att1 = pymc.TruncatedNormal('mu_att1', 0, .001, -3, 0, value=-.1)
mu_att3 = pymc.TruncatedNormal('mu_att3', 0, .001, 0, 3, value=.1)
tau_att = pymc.Gamma('tau_att', .01, .01, size=3, value=[10, 10, 10])
tau_def = pymc.Gamma('tau_def', .01, .01, size=3, value=[10, 10, 10])

pi_att = pymc.Dirichlet("grp_att", theta=[1,1,1]) 
group_att = pymc.Categorical('group_att', pi_att, size=num_teams)

pi_def = pymc.Dirichlet("grp_def", theta=[1,1,1])
group_def = pymc.Categorical('group_def', pi_def, size=num_teams)


@pymc.deterministic
def mu_atts(group_att=group_att, 
            mu_att1=mu_att1,
            mu_att3=mu_att3):
    mus_by_group = [mu_att1, 0, mu_att3]
    return [mus_by_group[i] for i in group_att]

@pymc.deterministic
def tau_atts(group_att=group_att, 
            tau_att=tau_att):
    return [tau_att[i] for i in group_att]

@pymc.deterministic
def mu_defs(group_def=group_def, 
            mu_def1=mu_def1,
            mu_def3=mu_def3):
    mus_by_group = [mu_def1, 0, mu_def3]
    return [mus_by_group[i] for i in group_def]

@pymc.deterministic
def tau_defs(group_def=group_def, 
            tau_def=tau_def):
    return [tau_def[i] for i in group_att]  

atts_star = np.empty(num_teams, dtype=object)
defs_star = np.empty(num_teams, dtype=object)

for i in range(num_teams):
    atts_star[i] = pymc.NoncentralT("att_%i" % i, mu=mu_atts[i], lam=tau_atts[i], nu=NCT_DOF)
    defs_star[i] = pymc.NoncentralT("def_%i" % i, mu=mu_defs[i], lam=tau_defs[i], nu=NCT_DOF)
```